# How to use shared preference with checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I am making a program in which I want to use an activity as a splash screen which shows a list of instruction which i am using as a background image, a checkbox and a button. I want that when the checkbox is clicked or onChecked and then I click the button, that activity should not be seen again at startup.
I am unable to figure out how to implement the code.

This is what I am doing but still no use

```
CheckBox cb;
SharedPreferences sp;
Button btn;
int result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    sp = (SharedPreferences) PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    OnCheckedChangeListener cb1 = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cb.isChecked()){


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putInt("showActivity", 0);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else{


                result = sp.getInt("showActivity", -1);
                if(result == 0){

                }
            }
        }
    };
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cb1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dgdgd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this when you click Ok button if checkbox clicked

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("showActivity", 0);
    editor.commit();
```

And when you launch your app check like this..

```
    int result;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    result = sharedPreferences.getInt("showActivity", -1);
    if(result == 0)
      // do not show the activity.. start the next activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are checking weather show `XYZActivity` or not.

Just write this in your button click

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("showActivity",cb.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

And next time check before starting XYZActivity.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("showActivity",false)){
   //check box is checked (no need to show activity)
}else{
   //show activity here    
}
```